# Google nexus one Macbook pro mismatch

Tags: android

I have this annoying issue where my android google nexus one can't run my application from a macbook pro using eclipse. It says "device not found".

The worst thing is that it used to work most of time when I was on 2.3.3 android version, but now I get the last version (ice cream sandwich I think - 4.0.3), it is still randomly working but 3 times out of a hundred.

This is a famous issue but so far I didn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue too and it seemed to be related to the USB hubs not working correctly. Trying [resetting your PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1379) and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok my mistake, it only worked two times, I'm back to the start now.

Comment: Ok so I figured out a kind of solution, based on yours : It's like randomly working again. So everytime my mac doesn't recognize the android phone, I disable and enable the debugger mode until it works. If after 10 try it still doesn't work, I use your reboot thing. It's annoying but at least I'm not completely stucked.

Comment: You can also try [repairing disk permissions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1452). Maybe try resetting the RAM on your nexus one too (i.e. ensure phone is discharging, power off, take the battery out for a couple minutes and then power on).

Comment: I'll try. Anyway you solved my problem even if it's not completely satisfying. Thanks !